# Elements position get changed after adding them as subView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, xcode5

I put a `UITextField`, a `UITextView` and another element to a `UIView` and set their position in **Utility Area** in **Xcode**. What I want to do is group them as a `subView` and apply some animations to the `subView`. 
But after adding them to the newly created `subView` change their position, look at this pictures (before and after adding them):
**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image: After]

The green `UITextField` is center aligned and the `UITextView` is disappeared! (I don't care about the `UILabel` and that horizontal line right now).

It's my code:

```
    CGRect oldPosition = taskTitle.frame;

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [view addSubview:taskTitle];
    [view addSubview:taskNote];
    [view addSubview:datePickerButton];

    taskTitle.frame=oldPosition;
    [self.view addSubview:view];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable autolayout from the file inspector, in Utilities bar.
It can be done by unchecking the Use `Autolayout` option.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]